# When copy the coupon using woocommerce coupons want to send email to user and admin and redirect to custom url

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

In my woocommerce website I want to integrate functionality- When order is confirmed on order-details page I want to show some woocommerce coupons, when user just copy or click on any coupon then admin and user will receive an email and then user redirect to external url.(all coupons are different with different urls and coupons).
Anyone help me for this?

Comment: I would recommend clicking over copy since will be tricky for mobile etc.. Just create ajax call on click to trigger wp_mail() function - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/ . After email is send you can add at the end https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/

Comment: Can you please share me the how to write this whole function ?

Comment: I mean how to pass the arguments when click on the coupons

Comment: Which filter we can use?

Comment: Here are some examples - https://www.learn-codes.net/php/how-to-pass-php-variable-to-wordpress-ajax-handler/ wp_ajax_nopriv and wp_ajax are the hooks you need. First one you may not need since user will be logged in.